# xDebug Profiling Failing & Errors

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug

Hi I have installed xDebug on an AWS server. Having thought I had set this up correctly I can not see anything being output at all. I was expecting a file to be appended to where I set the profiler_output_directory location.

Here is what phpinfo() has to say...

xdebug

xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.2.5
IDE Key no value

Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value

xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off

xdebug.cli_color    0   0

xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off

xdebug.collect_includes On  On

xdebug.collect_params   0   0

xdebug.collect_return   Off Off

xdebug.collect_vars Off Off

xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On

xdebug.default_enable   On  On

xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value

xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value

xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value

xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value

xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value

xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value

xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value

xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value

xdebug.dump_globals On  On

xdebug.dump_once    On  On

xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off

xdebug.extended_info    On  On

xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value

xdebug.idekey   no value    no value

xdebug.max_nesting_level    100 100

xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On

xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off

xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off

xdebug.profiler_enable  On  On

xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  On  On

xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /home/ec2-user/xdebug_logs  /home/ec2-user/xdebug_logs

xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p

xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off

xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off

xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600

xdebug.remote_enable    Off Off

xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp

xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost

xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value

xdebug.remote_mode  req req

xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000

xdebug.scream   Off Off

xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off

xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off

xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off

xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off

xdebug.trace_format 0   0

xdebug.trace_options    0   0

xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp    /tmp

xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c

xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128

xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512

xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3

Here is what is in apache's error log.

Failed loading /var/tmp/pear-build-rooth6C0Im/install-xdebug-2.2.5/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so:  /var/tmp/pear-build-rooth6C0Im/install-xdebug-2.2.5/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so: cannot open sh$
Failed loading xdebug.so:  xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Does anyone have a suggestion of where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making sure all the paths in php.ini were in quotes, before they were not.